# Is there definitive documentation regarding the reliability of a capacitive touchscreen?

Tags: capacitive, touchscreen

I'm working with a manufacturer who wants to use a touchscreen (like a mobile phone) to activate the machinery but is afraid the touchscreen could give a false reading.

This would be a touch-and-hold scenario, not just touch-to-activate. Humidity and moisture are not a concern in the given environment, and it's understood that physical objects could register a "touch."

So it becomes a question of whether a hardware failure or software failure in its processing, could cause the touchscreen to return a constant false touch in one region of the screen.

I was reading [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/509819/257655) to [Can a water drop do a “fake” touch on a capacitive touchscreen?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/16439/can-a-water-drop-do-a-fake-touch-on-a-capacitive-touchscreen) which seems to imply that the screen would require something in close proximity, but isn't the kind of solid reference that can conclude the discussion.

If possible, I'd like to point them at some documentation describing the reliability or possible failure scenarios of capacitive touchscreen hardware and processing.

Thanks

Comment: you should be asking one of the manufacturers of touch panel systems for industrial applications

Comment: i always turn on the "display touches" option on my android phone ... it displays a small circle at all of the touch points ... the phone i had a couple of years ago would detect water as a touch ... the phone i have now does not detect water ... same phone manufacturer ... so it is technology dependent

Comment: If there is any question of safety to personnel or property then I suggest that a touch screen on its own is not appropriate. A physical pushbutton + touch = maybe.

Comment: In my view the "engineering approach" should not be to focus on the **reliability** of the touch screen as **there can be no guarantee**. So **assume that false readings happen** and solve that by a confirmation press (or slide) elsewhere on the screen and/or a physical button. You might only need that for the functions that could potentially be dangerous when activated by false readings.

Comment: Digital filters in the software can filter out a valid "touch" from a button "press". A press can be faked by water drops. Also filters can ignore a "almost touch" that is too short in duration to be a valid key press. This is all built into the OS key-pad handler. Old versions of Android were lousy at key-pad operation but ver 9 and beyond have fixed many issues.